# Angular ngIf + bootstrap row: content of last div gets nested in previous div or is not rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm using ngIf on 3 divs in a row of 5 divs, the **content** of the last div is rendered inside the 2nd to last div or is not rendered at all even though **this last div does not have an ngIf applied to it**. Confused? Me too. Here's the details:

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-xs-24" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in SomeList">
    <div class="col-xs-5">{{item.Name}}:</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" ng-if="item.UsesRating"><input type="text" style="width: 100%" ng-model="item.Rating"/></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-if="item.UsesRating">/{{item.MaxRating}}</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" ng-if="!item.UsesRating">
        <select ng-model="e" class="form-control input-sm" ng-options="e.IsPassed as e.Description for e in EvaluationWithoutRating" name="evaluatie" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="item.Comment"/></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve the following using bootstrap cols:

I want either

**| div 1 | div 4 | div 5 |**

OR

**| div 1 | div 2 | div 3 | div 5 |**

What I'm getting is

**| div 1 | div 4 div 5 |**
(div 5 *content* nested in div 4)

OR

**| div 1 | div 2 | div 3 |**
 (div 5 not shown)

The generated HTML from the above snippet renders:

```
    <div class="col-xs-24" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<!-- ngRepeat: item in SomeList --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in SomeList">
    <div class="col-xs-5 ng-binding">test:</div>
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating --><div class="col-xs-2 ng-scope" ng-if="item.UsesRating"><input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" style="width: 100%;" type="text" ng-model="item.Rating"></div><!-- end ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating --><div class="col-xs-4 ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="item.UsesRating">/50</div><!-- end ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: !item.UsesRating -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: item in SomeList --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in SomeList">
    <div class="col-xs-5 ng-binding">testf sdf:</div>
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating --><div class="col-xs-2 ng-scope" ng-if="item.UsesRating"><input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" style="width: 100%;" type="text" ng-model="item.Rating"></div><!-- end ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating --><div class="col-xs-4 ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="item.UsesRating">/50</div><!-- end ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: !item.UsesRating -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: item in SomeList --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in SomeList">
    <div class="col-xs-5 ng-binding">testggdfg g:</div>
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: item.UsesRating -->
    <!-- ngIf: !item.UsesRating --><div class="col-xs-6 ng-scope" ng-if="!item.UsesRating"><select name="evaluatie" class="form-control input-sm ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" required="" ng-model="e" ng-options="e.IsPassed as e.Description for e in EvaluationWithoutRating"><option value="number:0" label="Geslaagd">Geslaagd</option><option value="number:1" label="Niet geslaagd">Niet geslaagd</option><input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" style="width: 100%;" type="text" placeholder="Comment" ng-model="item.Comment"></div><!-- end ngIf: !item.UsesRating -->
</div><!-- end ngRepeat: item in SomeList -->
```

edits: anglicized the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not closed `select` tag. Try closing and reloading the page.
Let me know, if that works.. :)